# Getting information from the PowerShell current state (or context) from C#

Tags: c#, powershell

I've seen some code samples that allow to load specific PowerShell scripts from C#, and then invoke specific functions form the scripts:

```
// "dot-source my functions"
ps.AddScript(". .\MyFunctions.ps1", $false)
ps.Invoke()
```

My question is -- now that this has been performed, all of the functions inside this file have been loaded globally; is there any way to access them as objects from C# code?

I'd like to be able to see from code, which functions have been loaded into the global context, and then analyze them (see their parameter list, etc).

Is this at all possible?

Thanks
Lior

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. There are many ways. Perhaps the easiest is to invoke "dir function:\". Now, that last sentence might bake your noodle a little but it's what I would do. It return a collection of FunctionInfo instances, on which there is a wealth of metadata.

Answer (score 2):

Another similar option,if you are using v2, would be to turn your PS1 file into a PSM1 (PowerShell Module) . Then from C# you could use the command

```
import-module path\to\module\myfunctions.psm1
```

From there, you could issue the command

```
get-command -module myfunctions
```